# Load swf file to be in the center in stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```html
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;

var url_request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('01.swf');
var swf_loader:Loader = new Loader();
    swf_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_Loaded);    
    swf_loader.load(url_request);
function on_Loaded(e:Event): void {
    swf_loader.width = 50;
    swf_loader.height = 50;
    addChild(swf_loader);}
```

When I try
swf_loader.align = Stage.align.CENTER,
it does not work. What could be wrong with my code?

Comment: consider adding a screenshot of the current behavior.   For exact alignments, you should always be using `stage.align =  StageAlign.TOP_LEFT` and `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE` OR `StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL`.   There is no such thing as `Stage.align.CENTER` and trying that will result in an error.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis You mean that there is no way in which the swf file in the center at stage.

Comment: There is a way, as described by @Jezzamon below.  Your issue may be in the nature of your child swf or more likely because you have an error somewhere.  Can you post your child swf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to handle the positioning relative to the stage that you're adding it to:

```
swf_loader.x = (stage.stageWidth - swf_loader.width) / 2;
swf_loader.y = (stage.stageHeight - swf_loader.height) / 2;
```

You need to do this once you've loaded the swf, so in the on_Loaded function, like so

```
function on_Loaded(e:Event): void {
    swf_loader.width = 50;
    swf_loader.height = 50;
    swf_loader.x = (stage.stageWidth - swf_loader.width) / 2;
    swf_loader.y = (stage.stageHeight - swf_loader.height) / 2;
    addChild(swf_loader);
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use x, y Because file (swf_loader) It does not work properly

Comment: Are there any other way?

Comment: @FlashGirl Could you give more details as to what happens that when you try this? Does an error message pop up? Have you managed to load the swf successfully in the first place?

Comment: swf_loader File does not work will correct at loaded in stage > When i select X, y >>swf_loader.x= 50; swf_loader.y= 50;

Comment: Buttons do not work, or when clicking on it or select an item in which

Comment: May be because I changed X and Y

Comment: ah, so later you are setting x and y to something else? that will undo this code.

Comment: yes ,The problem
  When you delete the x, y
swf File is loaded in 0.0 up the stage

Comment: I want i in the center in stage

Comment: @FlashGirl If I'm understanding correctly, you need to remove any other code that sets the x or y of `swf_loader`. Only set it once, in the `on_Loaded` event

Answer (score 1):

```
swfloader.y = (stage.StageHeight) / 2;
swfloader. x = (stage.StageWidth) / 2;
```

that is the centre of stage.

edit: no it is not.
this is the correct one;

```
swfloader.y = (stage.StageHeight / 2) - (swfloader.height / 2);
swfloader. x = (stage.StageWidth / 2) - (swfloader.width / 2);
```

Comment: I do not want to use x, y
Because  file (swf_loader) It does not work properly

Comment: Create a container and add swf into that. And attach the loader to the container. You can change `x`s and `y`s of container how you want.

Comment: i try that . i Create a Movie clip but It does not work properly also

Comment: Are there any other way?